# Laravel. Eager Load not working but relation exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a very strange Laravel issue that I can't explain and that has happened to me before without me being able to solve it.

**To explain, some (not all) of the relationships do not load when I load them via eager loading.**

For example, I have my User model and a Tag model. My user has 3 tags in the exemple. This is a classic *belongsToMany* relationship.

```
public function tags(): BelongsToMany {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'user_tags');
}
```

I want to retrieve tags of one user :

```
$user = User::with(['tags'])->findOrFail($randomId);
```

So, my user has 3 tags but when i'm doing the *dd* of the model the tags relashoship is empty (strange). But if i'm using the *withCount* method, tags_count equals 3. Moreover, if I do :

```
$tags = user->tags()->get();
```

I can retrieve the three tags.

So eager loading does not work only in some relationships, but i have an other strange situation. I wanted to know if it was my local environment. I deployed my software on a server and some of the broken eagerLod relationships are working in prod and some others are not still working...

I'm a senior laravel developer and after 3 days of search, I need help to find other resolution paths.

Thanks

Comment: please add the full user and tag models. how can we help you with 4 lines if code when you can't find the issue with all the code.

Comment: Yes i know but it's not related to the code because it was working well since two years. But i found a solution change the database name and deploy on a new database ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it happen to you, deploy on a new database.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).